# Ruby On Rails Collection Select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi I have been following this documentation

https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select

and still not having any luck on making it work on my app

I kept on receiving

wrong number of arguments (given 7, expected 4..6)

Model

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :school_degree

end



class SchoolDegree < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :school
   belongs_to :degree
   belongs_to :college
   has_many :students

    def self.test 
              "#{degree.name} - #{college.name}"

    end    


end
```

View

```
<%= f.collection_select(:student , :school_degree , SchoolDegree.all, :id, :test, {prompt: 'College Degree'},{class: "form-control"}) %>
```

Answer (score 4):

try this :

change your classs method to instance method,

```
class SchoolDegree < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :school
   belongs_to :degree
   belongs_to :college
   has_many :students

    def test 
       "#{degree.name} - #{college.name}"
    end    


end
```

in view;

```
<%= f.collection_select(:school_degree_id , SchoolDegree.all, :id, :test, {prompt: 'College Degree'},{class: "form-control"}) %>
```

Comment: still no luck  it gave me " wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2..3)"

Comment: got it working thank you so much! been trying to get this working for 2  days now!

Answer (score 1):

You should not need the :student

```
  <%= f.collection_select(:school_degree , SchoolDegree.all, :id, :test, {prompt: 'College Degree'},{class: "form-control"}) %>
```

I am seeing you are trying to use a class method while the example in the documentation is not. Is there a reason for that ? Try removing self like below

```
def test 
  "#{degree.name} - #{college.name}"
end
```

Comment: i have tried this earlier with no luck and it keeps on giving me this error "wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2..3)"

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :school_degree

    def test 
          "#{school_degree.degree.name} - #{school_degree.college.name}"

    end
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below

```
<%= f.collection_select :score_id, SchoolDegree.all, :id, :test, { :prompt => 'College Degree'},{ :class => "form-control" } %>
```

In **SchoolDegree** model

```
def test 
  "#{degree.name} - #{college.name}"
end
```

for more info follow below link

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select